# Room Database showing wrong data after deleting item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-viewmodel

I am using room database in my app.The app shows books  under three categories All Books,Home Books and Library Books.The app shows books data based on user selection.Everything works fine,the app shows correct category books,but when user deletes a Book from any category then the app and list refreshes, then some times app shows wrong data means if a user is viewing books under Home Books category and he deletes a book then the app shows him random books instead of showing his selected Home Books.
// This is how I am loading data:

```
 public void loadBooks(){
        if(booksType==1){
                    mBookViewModel.getAllBooks().observe(this, new Observer<List<Books>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Books>books) {
                                                 adapter.setBooks(books);
                        }
                    });
                }
     if(booksType==2){
                    mBookViewModel.getHomeBooks().observe(this, new Observer<List<Books>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Books>books) {
                            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                            adapter.setBooks(books);
                        }
                    });
                }
     if(booksType==3){
                    mBookViewModel.getLibrarayBooks().observe(this, new Observer<List<Books>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Books>books) {
                            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                            adapter.setBooks(books);
                        }
                    });
                }
    calculateSum();// calculating sum of values of a column.
    }

    public void calculateSum(){
    double total=mBookViewModel.getBookSum();
    }

  //  This how I am deleting a book:
    public void delete(Books book){


                   int rowsDeleted = mBookViewModel.deleteBook(book);


           loadBooks(); //have to call this method as I am doing other stuff also.Like calculating the sum of other integer fields.
    // suppose user is viewing Home Books(means bookType==2) after this call instead of showing user Home Books the app shows him any random list of books.It does not happen always but after user deletes five to six books continuously and fast.


    }

  //  My View Model:
      LiveData<List<Books>> getAllBooks() {return mRepository.getAllBooks(); }
     LiveData<List<Books>> getHomeBooks() {return mRepository.getHomeBooks(); }
     LiveData<List<Books>> getLibraryBooks() {return mRepository.getLibraryBooks(); }

     double getBookSum() {return mRepository.getBookSum(); }

  //  Repository:
      LiveData<List<Books>> getallBooks() {
            try {
                return new getAllBooksAsyncTask(mBooksDao).execute().get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

      private static class getAllBooksAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LiveData<List<Books>>> {
            private BooksDao mAsyncTaskDao;


            getAllBooksAscAsyncTask(BooksDao dao) {
                mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
            }

            @Override
            protected LiveData<List<Books>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                return mAsyncTaskDao.getAllBooks();
            }
        }

     LiveData<List<Books>> getallBooks() {
            try {
                return new getAllBooksAsyncTask(mBooksDao).execute().get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

      private static class getHomeBooksAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LiveData<List<Books>>> {
            private BooksDao mAsyncTaskDao;


            getHomeBooksAscAsyncTask(BooksDao dao) {
                mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
            }

            @Override
            protected LiveData<List<Books>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                return mAsyncTaskDao.getHomeBooks();
            }
        }

     LiveData<List<Books>> getallBooks() {
            try {
                return new getAllBooksAsyncTask(mBooksDao).execute().get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

      private static class getLibraryBooksAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LiveData<List<Books>>> {
            private BooksDao mAsyncTaskDao;


            getLibraryBooksAscAsyncTask(BooksDao dao) {
                mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
            }

            @Override
            protected LiveData<List<Books>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                return mAsyncTaskDao.getLibraryBooks();
            }
        }

      public double getBookSum() {
            try {
                return new getBookSumAsyncTask(mBookDao).execute().get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            }
        }

      private static class getBookSumAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Double> {

            private BookDao mAsyncTaskDao;

            getBookSumAsyncTask(BookDao dao) {
                mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
            }

            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                return mAsyncTaskDao.getBookSum();

            }
        }

 //   Dao:
       @Query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE type  = 1 ")
        LiveData<List<Books>> getAllBooks();

      @Query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE type  = 2 ")
        LiveData<List<Books>> getHomeBooks();

      @Query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE type  = 3 ")
        LiveData<List<Books>> getLibraryBooks();

      @Query("SELECT SUM(pages) FROM books ")
        double getBookSum();


 //   Recycler View:
      @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull booksRecyclerAdapter.BookViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if (mBookss != null) {
              Books current = mBooks.get(position);


                String name = current.getName();


                holder.nameTextView.setText(name);

            }
        }
     void setBooks(List<Books> book){
            mBooks = book;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
       @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (mBooks != null)
                return mBooks.size();
            else return 0;
        }
        public Books getBookAtPosition (int position) {
            return mBooks.get(position);
        }
```

I have tried adding  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and   adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position); but it does not work.Also,if there is something wrong in my codes then why it does not happen always,it happens sometimes usually after deleting five or six items continuously.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, what happens after you delete a book, then close, and reopen your app, does it shows the correct list without the deleted book or still having a problem?

Comment: When I close and reopens  the app it app shows correct data.It's only when user filter the data based on value of bookType and then edit or delete a book then the app does not show the data for the bookType which the user has earlier selected but instead shows  random data.And it does not happen always.I think when reloading the data the app does not properly read the value of bookType .

Answer (score 0):

After much trying I figured out that the problem was because of the adapter.The adapter was loading previously selected books list e.g. if a user first selects homeBooks and then selects allBooks and perform a delete query on any one book in allBooks list then after the delete operation instead of keeping the user on allBooks list the adapter was showing him homeBooks list. As I was using same adapter for all three cases.I think this may be a problem with Room Database .So,when I used different adapters for different cases everything worked as expected.I don't know whether this is the correct way to do it  but for now it is working.So the code now becomes

```
 public void loadBooks(){
        if(booksType==1){
   bookRecyclerAdapter adapter1=new bookRecyclerAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    mBookViewModel.getAllBooks().observe(this, new Observer<List<Books>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Books>books) {
                                                 adapter1.setBooks(books);
                        }
                    });
                }
     if(booksType==2){
  bookRecyclerAdapter adapter2=new bookRecyclerAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    mBookViewModel.getHomeBooks().observe(this, new Observer<List<Books>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Books>books) {
                            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                            adapter2.setBooks(books);
                        }
                    });
                }
     if(booksType==3){
  bookRecyclerAdapter adapter3=new bookRecyclerAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter3);
                    mBookViewModel.getLibrarayBooks().observe(this, new Observer<List<Books>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Books>books) {
                            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                            adapter3.setBooks(books);
                        }
                    });
                }
    calculateSum();// calculating sum of values of a column.
    }
```